# How to start working with HTML5 in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I am a magento developer and now want to start theme development using HTML5 and CSS3. Please help me for a start on this if any body can.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most logical place to start with an HTML5 theme is the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

All joking aside - theme development is a very broad and complex issue. I recommend you look at some existing HTML5 themes - to give you a working base and to broaden your understanding of Magento theming.

Below are all free themes:

**HTML5 Boilerplate**

https://github.com/zeljkoprsa/waterlee-boilerplate

**Magento's iPhone Theme is now HTML5:**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-mobile-html5-theme-6529.html

**Twitter Bootstrap:**

https://github.com/vsubotic/bootstrapped

---

**Read more:**

In addition here are some other resources to learn more about theming in general:

Alan Storm (literally) wrote the book on Magento Layout:

- http://alanstorm.com/new_book_no_frills_magento_layout

A little old, but still relevant:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/SWS-Theming-Aug10-handouts.pdf

Magento's own site has some good content, too:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Don't forget Magento U training - worth every penny:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand

Comment: This has happened before. I was about to write a similar answer. So +1. I might add a list of 'inspiration' material: http://www.templatemonster.com/responsive-magento-themes/

Comment: *Comment removed out of the same fear as phil*

Comment: Redacted my statement out of fear :)

Comment: Very useful &  Valuable. +1